# How to create a new data frame `df2` that summarises the number of rows of a data frame `df1` but conditioned to the DateTime

Tags: r

I have the data frame df1 which summarises detections in an area of different animals over time. The column `Receiver` specifies which device detected it, and the column `Transmitter` specifies which animal is (its "ID"). I want to create a new data frame `df2` in which I want to summarise the number of detections/rows for a transmitter/individual in a specific period of time. The columns I want are:
1) `Num_det`: for a specific transmitter (== individual) and a specific period of time, the number of rows (== detections). The intervals I want are from half-past of every hour until half-past of the next hour (00:30 to 01:30, 01:30 to 02:30, 03:30 to 04:30, etc).
2)  `Num_rec`: the number of different receivers that have caught the transmitter in this period of time.
3) `Which_rec`: the name of the different receivers that have caught the transmitter signal in this period of time.

As an example:

```
df1<-data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 15:01:45","2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 16:29:16","2016-08-01 16:33:16","2016-08-01 16:54:16","2016-08-01 16:58:16","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:28:16","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:42:08"),Receiver=c( "V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4" ),Transmitter=c(16 , 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 17))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")

df1
              DateTime Receiver Transmitter
1  2016-08-01 12:04:07       V6          16
2  2016-08-01 12:06:07       V7          17
3  2016-08-01 13:12:12       V6          16
4  2016-08-01 14:04:07       V6          16
5  2016-08-01 15:01:45       V7          17
6  2016-08-01 15:34:07       V7          16
7  2016-08-01 16:25:16       V6          17
8  2016-08-01 16:29:16       V6          16
9  2016-08-01 16:33:16       V6          16
10 2016-08-01 16:54:16       V7          16
11 2016-08-01 16:58:16       V7          17
12 2016-08-01 17:13:16       V7          16
13 2016-08-01 17:21:16       V6          16
14 2016-08-01 17:23:42       V6          17
15 2016-08-01 17:27:16       V6          17
16 2016-08-01 17:28:16       V9          17
17 2016-08-01 17:29:28       V7          16
18 2016-08-01 17:42:08       V4          17
```

What I want to get is:

```
df2
             RoundTime Transmitter Num_det Num_Rec Which_Rec
1  2016-08-01 12:00:00          16       1       1        V6 # The RoundTime "12:00:00" encompass from 11:30:00 to 12:30:00.
2  2016-08-01 12:00:00          17       1       1        V7 # At 12:00:00 there is a detection of the individual 17 in the receiver V7.
3  2016-08-01 13:00:00          16       1       1        V6
4  2016-08-01 13:00:00          17       0      NA        NA # At 13:00:00 there is no detection of individual 17 for any receiver.
5  2016-08-01 14:00:00          16       1       1        V6
6  2016-08-01 14:00:00          17       0      NA        NA
7  2016-08-01 15:00:00          16       0      NA        NA
8  2016-08-01 15:00:00          17       1       1        V7
9  2016-08-01 16:00:00          16       2       2     V6,V7
10 2016-08-01 16:00:00          17       1       1        V6
11 2016-08-01 17:00:00          16       5       2     V6,V7
12 2016-08-01 17:00:00          17       4       3  V6,V7,V9 # At 17:00:00 the individual 17 has been recorded 4 times for 3 different receivers.
13 2016-08-01 18:00:00          16       0      NA        NA
14 2016-08-01 18:00:00          17       1       1        V4
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `round_date` from `lubridate` and then do `group_by` to get the number of rows

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   # grouped by rounding the date by hour, Transmitter column
   group_by(RoundTime = round_date(DateTime, "hour"), Transmitter) %>% 
   # get the Num_det as number of rows, add more groups
   group_by(Num_det = n(), 
           which_Rec = toString(sort(unique(Receiver))), add = TRUE) %>%        
   # get the number of distinct elements of Receiver
   summarise(Num_Rec = n_distinct(Receiver)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   # expand the data to fill the missing combinations 
   complete(RoundTime, Transmitter, fill = list(Num_det = 0))%>% 
   select(RoundTime, Transmitter, Num_det, Num_Rec, which_Rec)
# A tibble: 14 x 5
#   RoundTime           Transmitter Num_det Num_Rec which_Rec 
#   <dttm>                    <dbl>   <dbl>   <int> <chr>     
# 1 2016-08-01 12:00:00          16       1       1 V6        
# 2 2016-08-01 12:00:00          17       1       1 V7        
# 3 2016-08-01 13:00:00          16       1       1 V6        
# 4 2016-08-01 13:00:00          17       0      NA <NA>      
# 5 2016-08-01 14:00:00          16       1       1 V6        
# 6 2016-08-01 14:00:00          17       0      NA <NA>      
# 7 2016-08-01 15:00:00          16       0      NA <NA>      
# 8 2016-08-01 15:00:00          17       1       1 V7        
# 9 2016-08-01 16:00:00          16       2       2 V6, V7    
#10 2016-08-01 16:00:00          17       1       1 V6        
#11 2016-08-01 17:00:00          16       5       2 V6, V7    
#12 2016-08-01 17:00:00          17       4       3 V6, V7, V9
#13 2016-08-01 18:00:00          16       0      NA <NA>      
#14 2016-08-01 18:00:00          17       1       1 V4
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect :). I'm doing my PhD and I'm very grateful for your help. Can I ask you something? Previous to this step, I have to "clean" my data frame of "false detections" (a receiver catches more than once a transmitter in an interval of 55s) and "multiple detections" (one emitted signal of a transmitter in a specific time is recorded by different receivers that are around my area). But I don't know how to do it neither. I posted this in StackOverflow too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664639/how-to-reduce-a-data-frame-considering-time-windows-in-which-only-the-1st-row